# Check if docker used cache for build or not

Tags: docker

is there any way to check if Docker used cache on **every** step of *Docker build* ?

Return value is 0 for successfull build - not saying anything about whether steps have been performed using cache or not.

I'm executing docker commands in bash script running in circleci environment and I'd like to skip *Docker save*, if every build step ran through cache.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Check it where/how? The way your question is phrased, you can just look at the terminal output - if it hits the cache on the last step, it hit the cache on every step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the easiest way is to compare at the image ID - if this hasn't changed, the cache must have been used.

Answer (score 0):

One interesting thing about the cache is that once one command invalidates it, all following commands skip it. From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/):

> Once the cache is invalidated, all subsequent Dockerfile commands will generate new images and the cache will not be used.

This means that if your last step is cached, all other steps before it were cached too - and your image has not changed.